# Set font color of items in DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

How can I set the color of the font for different items in a DataGridViewComboBoxCell? For example if I have 10 items, how would I make items 3 and 5 Red and leave the others black?

EDIT:  This is for a winform application and the DataGridViewComboBox is not data bound

edit2 :  Maybe I could do it here in the editcontrolshowing?

```
   private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
   {
            if (dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name == "MyCombo")
            {

                DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.CurrentCell;

                for (int i = 0; i < comboCell.Items.Count; ++i)
                {
                    string contract = comboCell.Items[i].ToString();
                    if (contract.ToUpper().Contains("NO"))
                    {
                        // can I set this item have a red font color???
                    }

                }
}
```

Comment: I posted a quick and dirty way below.. if you don't want to do it for the whole column / row then change the object ie the combobox cell something like this should help to get you started..

Comment: possible duplicate of [To change the DataGridViewComboBoxCell color(style) dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242308/to-change-the-datagridviewcomboboxcell-colorstyle-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

for rows do below - 
hook up **OnRowDataBound** event then do stuff

ASPX (Grid):

```
    <asp:.... OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound"..../>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex == -1)
        {
            return;
        }

        if(e.Row.Cells[YOUR_COLUMN_INDEX].Text=="NO"){
             e.Row.BackColor=Color.Red;   
        }
    }
```

FOR WinForms:

```
hook the **DataBindingComplete** event and do stuff in it:

     private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, 
                       DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ListChangedType != ListChangedType.ItemDeleted)
        {
            DataGridViewCellStyle red = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Clone();
            red.BackColor=Color.Red;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (r.Cells["FollowedUp"].Value.ToString()
                       .ToUpper().Contains("NO"))
                {
                    r.DefaultCellStyle = red;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I should have noted these details.  This is for a Winform application and the DataGridViewComboBox is not databound.

Comment: Were you able to still utilize the code and place it inside a different Event Handler..?

Comment: After looking at the code again I realized that it will change the entire combo box to a new color, not the individual items in the datagridviewcombobox so I won't be able to use that code

Comment: you can use the code you just have to assign the new color based on the index have you done any googling on this..

Comment: the combobox in order to do what you are talking about you would have to add the Object to the combobox with it's property already changed let me google something for you.. I am busy on another project but I will check something right now give me a sec..

Comment: here is a link that has a sample you can use their If condition or change it to a Switch {} Case: statement http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_23623785.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw the ComboBox items manually. Try the following (based on [this MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/8b5f5bc9-db56-4843-9714-8d4e125fb592)):

```cs
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    // Note this assumes there is only one ComboBox column in the grid!
    var comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
    if (comboBox == null)
        return;

    comboBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    comboBox.DrawItem -= DrawGridComboBoxItem;
    comboBox.DrawItem += DrawGridComboBoxItem;
}

private void DrawGridComboBoxItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();

    if (e.Index != -1)
    {
        // Determine which foreground color to use
        var itemValue = actionsColumn.Items[e.Index] as string;
        bool isNo = String.Equals("no", itemValue, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        Color color = isNo ? Color.Red : e.ForeColor;

        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(color))
            e.Graphics.DrawString(itemValue, e.Font, brush, e.Bounds);
    }

    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```